# I need to filter using multiple conditions in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, multiple-conditions

So I have been charged with coming up with an Excel program that can hide rows assuming different conditions are met. To describe the type of data:

Column A, Row 2: Company Name

Column W, Row 3-7: Transaction Amount

Column X, Row 7: Sum of the transactions

I need to hide all companies whose transactions do not total 600 or more. If they do total 600 or more, I need all of the transactions to remain visible as well as the company name and the total. Very few companies share the same number of transactions so I originally set it up to check an empty cell in the company's name row. I don't have the code here since it is on my work computer (obviously, this is driving me insane right now). It was something like this:

```
    Sub Totals()
       lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "W").End(xlUp).Row
       FirstRow = 2
       TempTotal = 0
       For x = FirstRow To lastrow + 1
           If Cells(x, "W") <> "" Then
               TempTotal = TempTotal + Cells(x, "W")
                       
           Else:   Cells(x - 1, "X") = TempTotal
                   TempTotal = 0
           End If
        Next x
    End Sub
```

I used this to sum the transactions. I was hoping to be able to use a nested If statement to print the transactions sum totals and, if they are less than 600, hide the relevant rows within the same code. I just have no idea how to specify the whole section... Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will *specify the whole section* and hide all relevant rows company name (Col A), transactions (Col W) and totals (Col X) for companies whose totals are less than 600.  Companies whose totals are >= 600 will remain visible.

```
Option Explicit
Sub HideBelow600()

Dim LastRow As Long, topRow As Long, bottomRow As Long, i As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
LastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 24).End(xlUp).Row

For i = LastRow To 2 Step -1
    If ws.Cells(i, 24).Value < 600 And ws.Cells(i, 24) <> "" Then
        bottomRow = i
        topRow = ws.Cells(i, 24).Offset(0, -1).End(xlUp).Row - 1
            ws.Range(Sheet3.Cells(topRow, 24), ws.Cells(bottomRow, 24)).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! Made my life so much easier!! It's odd, because I got a 1004 error when i ran it, but it still did the filtering. Thanks!!!